# I'm writing a wrapper library in c# for c++ using the dll's header file, but can't figure out how to convert types.

Tags: c#, c++, windows, interop

I have a struct in the c++ header file that looks like:

```
typedef struct sFrameOfData
{
    int            iFrame;                  
    float          fDelay;                 
    int            nBodies;                 
    sBodyData      BodyData[MAX_N_BODIES]; 

    int            nUnidentifiedMarkers;    
    tMarkerData*   UnidentifiedMarkers;    

    sAnalogData    AnalogData;              

    sRecordingStatus RecordingStatus;      

}
```

where `sAnalogData`,`tMarkerData`, and `sRecordingStatus` are custom c++ structs. 
The c# method being called is:

```
[DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll")]
    public static extern unsafe sFrameOfData* Cortex_GetCurrentFrame();
```

and I rewrote the structs as:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public unsafe struct sFrameOfData
    {
        private readonly int iFrame; //!< Cortex's frame number
        private readonly float fDelay; //!< Total time (seconds) from Camera to the Host sending the data

        private readonly int nBodies; //!< The bodies should match the descriptions

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100)] private readonly sBodyData BodyData;
        //!< The data for each body

        private readonly int nUnidentifiedMarkers; //!< Number of unrecognized markers
        private readonly tMarkerData* UnidentifiedMarkers; //!< The unrecognized markers

        private readonly sAnalogData AnalogData; //!< The analog data packaged

        private readonly sRecordingStatus RecordingStatus; //!< Info about name and frames being recorded
    }
```

but I get `cannot marshal 'return value'. Pointers cannot reference marshaled structures.`

Comment: Can you show your pinvoke code? Have you tried with  `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvenction.Cdecl)]`?. You'll probably need to write a marshaler in C++/CLI to map the unmanaged class pointer to a managed object

Comment: Hey the pinvoke code is: CortexDll.sFrameOfData* a = CortexDll.Cortex_GetCurrentFrame();

Comment: How would I go about writing a  marshaller?

Comment: Try with `[DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll"), CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi]`

Comment: Tried adding [DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)] and gives me the same error.

Comment: You have to declare the return value as IntPtr and marshal it yourself with Marshal.PtrToStructure().  The odds that this can come to a good end are rather low, very unclear who owns memory and how it should be released.  This function is quite hard to call reliably from a unmanaged program, that does *not* get better when you use pinvoke.  Best to use C++/CLI.

Comment: Ah. Is there any chance you could point me to an example of this being done. My background is not c++ and it is proving challenging to work with this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably start with the following skeleton.

Create a managed class to hold the data:

```
public class FrameOfData
{
    public int iFrame { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Mark the return value of the p/invoke import with *MarshalAs* indicating a class that will do the custom marshal (i.e. *FrameMarshaler* class):

```
[DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(FrameMarshaler))]
public static extern FrameOfData Cortex_GetCurrentFrame();
```

The *FrameMarshaler* class is responsible of doing the custom marshaling, receiving a pointer to the unmanaged struct and returning a managed *object*, this can be done in the *MarshalNativeToManaged* method:

```
public class FrameMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
        public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj)
        {
        }
        public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
        {
        }
        public int GetNativeDataSize()
        {
            return -1;
        }
        public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
        {
            // Here, we call C++/CLI code
            FrameOfData frame = Marshaler.MarshalFrame(pNativeData);    
            return frame;
        }   
}
```

The method *Marshaler.MarshalFrame* will be on a C++/CLI assembly.
The following code is an example of a C++/CLI marshaler for the struct:

```
#include "Cortex_SDK.h"
#pragma once

using namespace System;

public ref class Marshaler
{
    public:
        static FrameOfData^ MarshalFrame(IntPtr dispo)
        {
            // Cast the IntPtr to the unmanaged pointer
            sFrameOfData* unmanaged = static_cast<sFrameOfData*>(dispo.ToPointer());
            // Transform unmnaged pointer to a managed object
            FrameOfData^ managed = gcnew FrameOfData();
            managed->iFrame = unmanaged.iFrame;
            // ...
        }
}
```

Comment: This looks very helpful I am going to get working on it now. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: I'm assuming too many things because of my ignorance on the Cortex SDK, hope it helps

Comment: Quick question, but in the C++/CLI assembly, where does FrameOfData^ come from?

Comment: You probably need to have the FrameOfData class definition in a common assembly that can be referenced by both, your wrapper and the C++ assembly.